# react navigation tab screen icon color props type

Tags: react-native, eslint, react-proptypes, eslint-config-airbnb

I use eslint with vs code for my react native project .

I created a bottom tabs navigation using react navigation v5 :

```
 ...
   <Tab.Screen
        name="Contacts"
        component={ContactStackScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Contacts',
          tabBarColor: COLORS.DEFAULT,
          tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="contacts" color={color} size={26} />
          ),
        }}
       ...
```

I got eslint error for color props :

'color' is missing in props validation

I tried to fix it :

```
ButtomTabs.propTypes = {
  color: PropTypes.string,
};
```

but i got this error :

propType "color" is not required, but has no corresponding defaultProps declaration

Comment: Maybe `activeTintColor` and `inactiveTintColor` props [Docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#activetintcolor)

Comment: tabBarIcon
Function that given { focused: boolean, color: string, size: number } returns a React.Node, to display in the tab bar.  // in the doc of react navigation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there's a misunderstanding by the previous answers as to what is causing eslint to throw the `react/prop-types` error in this case. The lint error is correct - what's missing is the props validation for the arrow function introduced for `tabBarIcon`. Since that arrow function returns a React component, eslint is correct in enforcing the `react/prop-types` rule. To satisfy the rule, you need to provide prop types for that arrow function (think of the arrow function as an anonymous component which takes `color` as a prop). Just add `{color: string}` as the type definition for the entire parameter of that arrow function like this:

```
({color}: {color: string}) =>
```

In context:

```
<Tab.Screen
        name="Contacts"
        component={ContactStackScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Contacts',
          tabBarColor: COLORS.DEFAULT,
          tabBarIcon: ({color}: {color: string}) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="contacts" color={color} size={26} />
          ),
        }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ignore the warning. It's a false positive.

1. `tabBarIcon` isn't a component and `propTypes` are only applicable to components
2. You're adding `propTypes` on `BottomTabs` component, but the warning is likely from the eslint plugin assuming that the function passed to `tabBarIcon` is a component

Comment: can you show me a good config for eslint with vscode and react native please ?

Comment: This is my config https://github.com/satya164/eslint-config-satya164

Comment: and what about the content of .eslintrc.js please ?

Comment: Read the README on how to use it, if you're just looking for the content of the config then check the index.js file

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation,

> tabBarIcon is a supported option in bottom tab navigator. So we know we can use it on our screen components in the options prop, but in this case chose to put it in the screenOptions prop of Tab.Navigator in order to centralize the icon configuration for convenience.
> here is an example of using `Icon` with `Tab.Screen`

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function MyTabs() {
return (
<Tab.Navigator
  initialRouteName="Feed"
  tabBarOptions={{
    activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
  }}
>
  <Tab.Screen
    name="Feed"
    component={Feed}
    options={{
      tabBarLabel: 'Home',
      tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
        <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={size} />
      ),
    }}
  />
  <Tab.Screen
    name="Notifications"
    component={Notifications}
    options={{
      tabBarLabel: 'Updates',
      tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
        <MaterialCommunityIcons name="bell" color={color} size={size} />
      ),
    }}
  />
  <Tab.Screen
    name="Profile"
    component={Profile}
    options={{
      tabBarLabel: 'Profile',
      tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
        <MaterialCommunityIcons name="account" color={color} size={size} />
      ),
    }}
  />
</Tab.Navigator>
```

);
}

Comment: hello i tried to put the config in the screenOptions but i got the same error, is about the prop type